# Touchend fires on touchstart second time around

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, touch

Does anyone know why a touchend event would fire during a touchstart event? This only happens the second time around.

A quick code snippet:

```
function touchstart (event) {
    $(event.target).one('touchend', function () {
        alert('fired');
    }
}
```

So the first time this is fired it works fine. Second time it fires the alert on touchstart.

http://jsfiddle.net/8SVFR/

Edit:

Looks like this could be an iPhone issue only

Comment: Are we talking about mobile phone browser?
Works just fine on my Android 4.1 native browser.

Comment: Works fine too in Chrome and Firefox (mobile) on Android 4.1 too.

Comment: Only tried it on iPhone and it fires on touchstart the second time around

Comment: I've noticed, depending on the Android version and device sometimes a touch does not get exactly recognized, escpeciall on small buttons. Maybe this is the case?

Here's an improved fiddle with a bigger button and logging to the documents body using `html()`: http://jsfiddle.net/tuGZx/1/

Comment: Ok what's weird is if you put in an alert into this updated jsfiddle it fires again on the second touchstart. To get this to work you need to hold the button for a bit. Maybe it's just the alert firing it again?

Comment: I had experiences with different behaviours of `touch` and `mouse` events on Android and Android devices. If I remember correctly, iPhone >= 4 had no general problems with the `touch` event. I don't have a iPhone at hand, so I can't test it.

Comment: This sounds feasible.

@EggCup could you please add a "iphone" tag and extend the description.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out...by having an alert fire in a touchend event causes all sorts of problems. When you click 'ok' it fires the touchstart so the touchend gets fired next time you touch the element. Luckily I was using the alert to check my code - so once this was removed my code worked perfectly!

Comment: spent last night debugging this issue - works fine in Chrome with touch emulation, triggers callback twice on iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Just put code of "touchend" handler in setTimeout with 0ms. Like this:

```
$(someElement).on("touchend",
function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    /*Your code*/
    }, 0);
});
```